# Entity Framework - Missing column(s)?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

[Model Image http://screencast.com/t/ODkwZDQx](http://screencast.com/t/ODkwZDQx)
http://screencast.com/t/ODkwZDQx

I have a simple 3 table model built from my DB.  Company has 0 or more ProductsSold.  Company has 0 or 1 AutoNegotiationDetails.  As you see from the diagram, this is what is modeled.  However, in the ProductsSold Mapping Details you can see that the CompanyId Value/Property is missing.  Nor can I add it.  I have discovered that I can get to it programatically by going to ProductsSold.Company.CompanyId.

1) Is this correct?
2) Why does EF hide the FK field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Originally Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/) did not support foreign keys or hid them. In a podcast with Julia Lerman, she mentions foreign keys were not included to avoid the scenario of multiple joins to get data. Also in the [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/) it mentions "people say FKs pollute the conceptual model". Since this was such a divided subject the Entity Framework team has decide to  [add foreign key support in VS 2010 Beta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/).

In .Net 4 they have added FK Associations. You can read about them [on the EF blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/efdesign/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework).